# Specific model for the errors used by nlme::lme with AR1 errors

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I want to fit the model
$$Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + u_i + \epsilon_{it},$$
where $u_i$ are iid $N(0,\sigma_u^2)$, $\epsilon_{i0}\sim N\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\gamma^2} \right)$, and
$$ \epsilon_{it}=\gamma \epsilon_{i,t-1}+\delta_{it}$$
for $t>1$ with $\delta_{it}$ iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$. In other words, the process $\{ \epsilon_{it} \}_{t=0}^T$ is stationary with ${\rm Var}[\epsilon_{it}]=\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\gamma^2}$ for all $t$.

The `nlme::lme` function with argument `correlation = corAR1()` seems designed for this situation. However, I can't find any documentation about how the distribution of $\epsilon_{i0}$ is handled. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you describe there is called a stationary Gaussian AR1 process, see the first two slides regarding the distribution of Y0 in such a process: https://hedibert.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/AR1-and-AR2-processes.pdf I'm pretty sure that's what is implemented in package nlme. Unfortunately, Pinheiro and Bates (2000) appear to never state so explicitly.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, the epsilon_{it}'s follow a stationary Gaussian AR1 process (though the Y_{it}'s don't). Thanks for your comment.